# How to make calendar start at first day of month?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I have a function which checks how many days are in the current month:

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
   return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
var DaysInCurrentMonth = daysInMonth(month +1, year +1);
```

The answer to this is `> 31` for month December 2016.
Then I fill my calendar with this answer using the function below, but it of course makes it start at Monday, while the first day of this month is actually Thursday (1st of December is Thursday).

```
for (var i = 1; i < DaysInCurrentMonth + 1; i++) {
    divDag = document.createElement('div');
    divDag.className = 'dagBlokje';
    divDag.innerHTML = i;
    KalenderDagen.appendChild(divDag);
    if (i == Today) {
        divDag.className = 'dagBlokje today';
    }
}
```

How to make it so it will start at the first day?

Comment: Tell me if more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in the Date() constructor, month is numbered from 0-11, so 0=January and 11=December.

Then, I would encapsulate any logic for actually getting the number of day in the month in the function itself, rather than what you pass it.

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
}
var currentDate = new Date();
var DaysInCurrentMonth = daysInMonth(currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getFullYear());
```

That loop looks fine, but without information on your calendar structure, I can't say for sure. I would imagine any further issues you're having arise from mixing up months' numerical values.